# Windows authentication in app.config?

Tags: c#, database-connection, console-application

In web.config, to use windows domain authentication, I am aware to do the following:

```
<add name="MSSQL" connectionString="server=devserver;database=DBNAME;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
.
.
.
<system.web>

<identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\username" password="password" />
</system.web>
```

I wish to know about how do I achieve the same in windows application with app.config file?

I am using the same connection string as above, which enables my app to connect through the logged-in user.

BUT, I wish to connect through a specific user.

In web.config, I could add the identity tag inside system.web; but what is the equivalent of the same in app.config?

Please note that I will need to use a connection string since the app is huge and the connection string is used to connect to the DB in numerous place.

Comment: The process runs using the logged in users credentials so you shouldn't need to use impersonation, unless the users of the app is not authentication with the domain.

Comment: How to make it with a specific user rather than the logged in user?? Logged in user can be anyone, but I want to make it run through specific domain account like I can do in my web.config

Answer (score 3):

I assumed that you are using SQL Server.

Use this in app.config:

```
<configuration>
     <appSettings>
        <add key="ConnectionString" value="????????????"/>
      </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

???????????? replace as below

with SQL Login

```
"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MYDatabaseName;Connect Timeout=50;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MYUserName;Password=MYPassword
```

with Window Login

```
"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MYDatabaseName;Connect Timeout=50;Persist Security Info=True
```

and when you passing connection string to sql connection use this

```
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]
```

or

```
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[0]
```

Comment: Windows login -- how to make it with a specific user rather than the logged in user??

Comment: to connect SQL Server we need user login and there are two types of login 1 ) SQL 2) windows... you was not mention that you are using which sql, SQL server, Mysql, Oracle tec so i Assumed as sql server, make SQL Login instead of windows login

Comment: Yes, MSSQL. But only through a login account that I specify... not the default logged in user. I need to connect through windows login. I have mentioned in my main post.

Comment: I already know these! Have you read my question? How do I connect to MSSQL using a domain user of my choice rather than the current logged in user ?? Unfortunately, I cannot downvote your answer

Comment: yes but i already mensioned that .... and for connection string you can use Server=your domin name where is your database located;Database=myDataBase;Uid=user name which is provided by your database host;Pwd=password which is provided by your databasehost;
AllowZeroDateTime=True;